# Reload jDatatable using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I am new to web development and I need help to reload jquery datatable on dropdown event change.
any ideas and suggesstion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fnDraw() for this:

```
$('#myselectlist').change(function (e) {
        MyDataTable.fnDraw();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the creation of you datatable in a function, like:

```
function buildTable(someParameter){
   var myTable = $('#table_id').dataTable({
        "bDestroy" : true,
        ...
   });
}
```

... then, on change event on your dropdown, you can simply call the method with the selected option in your dropdown:

```
$('#dropdown_id').on('change', function() {
  buildTable($(this).val());
});
```

Note: the ["bDestroy" : true] allows the table to be redrawn at build while not reloading the page.